# Add Programatically created LinearLayout as resource to View in Fragment

Tags: android, layout

My eventual goal is to have users be able to switch between tabs with dynamically generated content (based on user input) in an activity. I am trying to create a dynamic layout and have it load as the layout within a fragment. My code is throwing an error because the layout I am trying to provide is not an xml resource. Is what I'm trying even possible to do?

```
public static class JobsFragment extends Fragment{
    LinearLayout l;
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            //set button vars here
            Log.i("aaa","called frag onCreate");
            l=new LinearLayout(getActivity());
            Button b=new Button(getActivity());
           b.setText("HI");
           l.addView(b);
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i("aaa","called frag onCreateView()");
        //View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_section_dummy, container, false);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(l, container, false);
        return rootView;
        }
    }
    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to one of the primary
     * sections of the app.
     */
    public static class AppSectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

        public AppSectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int i) {
            Fragment fragment = new JobsFragment();
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return "Section " + (position + 1);
        }   
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the fragment constructor accept linearlayout as parameter and use this field to be return from onCreateView

Something like following psuedo code

```
  CustomFragment{
   private LinearLayout mLayout;

    CustomFragment(LinearLayout layout){
     mLayout=layout;
|   }

    onCreatView(....)
    {
     return mLayout;
    }
}
```

Comment: I also needed to use @Amrut suggestion to fix my code. This did the trick however. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add layout width and height programatically. 
Without which it will throw error about mandatory layout parameters not provided. 
addLayoutParams is the method name